# RubyMine ignores rbenv setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, rbenv

I have rbenv installed and `rbenv global` is `2.3.0`. However when I open a rails project I haven't previously opened in RubyMine, it doesn't pick up the ruby version from `rbenv`, instead it uses the older version of ruby installed. Is this a bug in RubyMine or am I missing something?

**Update**: JetBrains confirmed in a support ticket that this is not currently supported. They said "please vote for feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-14110. [How to vote](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications).

Comment: Does the project you're opening have an `.rbenv-gemset` file, or similar?

Comment: @TomLord No I don't have `.rbenv-gemset`

Comment: I recommend contact support@jetbrains.com.  I've found them to be very helpful.

Comment: Is the ruby version specified in the `Gemfile`? Or in `.env`? Can you see anything at all which might override the global config?

Comment: @TomLord Gemfile has `ruby '2.3.0'`

Comment: That seems like a pretty major oversight considering how popular `rbenv` is.

Comment: It's easy to point RubyMine at the correct version, however.